# Add a class to panel page body element

Tags: 7, hooks, panels

How do I add a class to a panel page's body element without having to add it manually in the variant configuration section?  I want all panel pages to have a body element with the class 'panel-page'.  Is there some kind of hook like hook_panel_page()?

Answer (score 2):

You can use menu_get_item() to inspect what generated the page and add a class to the body element in template_preprocess_html(). I saw the code first in the Zen theme, where they also add a class if the page was generated by Views. [Link to Zen template.php](http://drupalcode.org/project/zen.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-5.x:/template.php)

```
    function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
      // Store the menu item.
      $variables['menu_item'] = menu_get_item();
      if ($variables['menu_item']) {
        switch ($variables['menu_item']['page_callback']) {
          case 'page_manager_blog':
          case 'page_manager_blog_user':
          case 'page_manager_contact_site':
          case 'page_manager_contact_user':
          case 'page_manager_node_add':
          case 'page_manager_node_edit':
          case 'page_manager_node_view_page':
          case 'page_manager_page_execute':
          case 'page_manager_poll':
          case 'page_manager_search_page':
          case 'page_manager_term_view_page':
          case 'page_manager_user_edit_page':
          case 'page_manager_user_view_page':
            // Is this a Panels page?
            $variables['classes_array'][] = 'page-panels';
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To override the default template, copy panels-pane.tpl.php from panels > templates to your theme, and clear the cache.
Then, manually add the CSS classes you need in your template file.